# When Charles is running the error disappears, when closed it returns

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, charles-proxy

Ok so I am trying to fix a issue where IE8 gets pushed into compatibility mode by something on the homepage and I cannot reproduce it in a local environment. I used **Charles** to map local the site's css file and narrowed the issue to a font that was being loaded. When I took the font out of the css, things seemed to be fixed. So I deployed the change.

When I was sure everything was deployed the issue was still happening. So I opened **Charles** to try to break down the html and see exactly where the issue was coming from but when **Charles** is open and running with Windows Proxy the issue disappears. I have turned off all other settings and tried throttling on a few different levels.

Has anyone else run into this kind of thing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be because you have [No Caching](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/no-caching/) setup and it might be messing with your headers.

> HOW IT WORKS
>
> The No Caching tool prevents caching by manipulating the HTTP headers
>   that control the caching of responses. The If-Modified-Since and
>   If-None-Match headers are removed from requests, Pragma: no-cache and
>   Cache-control: no-cache are added. The Expires, Last-Modified and ETag
>   headers are removed from responses and Expires: 0 and Cache-Control:
>   no-cache are added.

Comment: Thats it exactly. Thanks!